# How can i take variable from a text file using grep and sed?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

i have text file :

```
"NAME": "Linda",
    "AGE": "34",
"NAME": "Arnold",
    "AGE": "99",
```

and i want to get arnol's age : 99

i try this --> `cat file.txt | grep "AGE" | sed -n 2p`

output :  "AGE": "99",

how can i output only 99?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace your `sed` command with

```
sed -n '2 s/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p'
```

It will extract just the value in the last pair of quotes.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/DD0Ies).